# Segmentation fault in SOAP after upgrade PHP from v5.4.45 to v5.6.21

Tags: php, web-services, soap, centos, segmentation-fault

I'm receiving a segmentation fault after an upgrade of PHP from version v5.4.45 to v5.6.21. I've read the documentation for upgrading PHP, and there's no mentioning of any breaking changes in SOAP.

I tested this in an test environment which has the same versions. However, in our production environment, this fails. The call which is failing talks with a SOAP service and uses the `SoapClient` in PHP.

I'm not very familiar with debugging these kind of stack traces, but from my understanding, it looks like it's in the SOAP library somewhere it fails.

Versions of software running on the server (both test and production environment):

- PHP `5.6.21`
- MySQL `5.5.49 MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi`
- CentOS: `centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64`

Stack trace with debug symbols:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  master_to_zval_int (encode=0x2d9, data=0x7fb62db0aee0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:585
585             if (encode->to_zval) {
#1  0x00007fb6167d04f2 in model_to_zval_object (ret=0x7fb62ebc4738, model=0x7fb62fba4ca8, data=0x7fb62fbdac50, sdl=0x7fb62db91f30) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:1403
#2  0x00007fb6167d01f6 in model_to_zval_object (ret=0x7fb62ebc4738, model=0x7fb62fba4c28, data=0x7fb62fbdac50, sdl=0x7fb62db91f30) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:1459
#3  0x00007fb6167d0877 in to_zval_object_ex (type=<value optimized out>, data=0x7fb62fbdac50, pce=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:1589
#4  0x00007fb6167ce163 in master_to_zval_int (encode=0x7fb62e7836f0, data=0x7fb62fbdac50) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:586
#5  0x00007fb6167d04f2 in model_to_zval_object (ret=0x7fb62ebc4340, model=0x7fb62fba49e8, data=0x7fb62fbdabd0, sdl=0x7fb62db91f30) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:1403
#6  0x00007fb6167d01f6 in model_to_zval_object (ret=0x7fb62ebc4340, model=0x7fb62fba4968, data=0x7fb62fbdabd0, sdl=0x7fb62db91f30) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:1459
#7  0x00007fb6167d0877 in to_zval_object_ex (type=<value optimized out>, data=0x7fb62fbdabd0, pce=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:1589
#8  0x00007fb6167ce163 in master_to_zval_int (encode=0x7fb62e783738, data=0x7fb62fbdabd0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_encoding.c:586
#9  0x00007fb6167e32df in parse_packet_soap (this_ptr=<value optimized out>, buffer=<value optimized out>, buffer_size=<value optimized out>, fn=0x7fb62f990b80, fn_name=<value optimized out>, return_value=0x7fb62ebc6428, soap_headers=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_packet_soap.c:328
#10 0x00007fb6167c37e8 in do_soap_call (this_ptr=0x7fb62ebbe470, function=<value optimized out>, function_len=<value optimized out>, arg_count=1, real_args=0x7fb62fa1b750, return_value=0x7fb62ebc6428, location=0x7fb62db932b8 "https://winorgws.flt.no/prod/srv/wsWebUser.asmx", soap_action=<value optimized out>, call_uri=<value optimized out>, soap_headers=0x0, output_headers=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/soap.c:2780
#11 0x00007fb6167c41ec in zim_SoapClient___call (ht=<value optimized out>, return_value=0x7fb62ebc6428, return_value_ptr=<value optimized out>, this_ptr=0x7fb62ebbe470, return_value_used=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/soap.c:2950
#12 0x00007fb62102ab69 in dtrace_execute_internal (execute_data_ptr=<value optimized out>, fci=<value optimized out>, return_value_used=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:97
#13 0x00007fb62102d904 in zend_call_function (fci=0x7fffc3a8b840, fci_cache=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:849
#14 0x00007fb6210535c7 in zend_call_method (object_pp=0x7fffc3a8b960, obj_ce=<value optimized out>, fn_proxy=0x7fb62d7c2d88, function_name=0x7fb6211417f2 "__call", function_name_len=<value optimized out>, retval_ptr_ptr=0x7fffc3a8b978, param_count=2, arg1=0x7fb62ebc6368, arg2=0x7fb62ebc63c8) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_interfaces.c:97
#15 0x00007fb621065ae2 in zend_std_call_user_call (ht=<value optimized out>, return_value=0x7fb62ebc3dc0, return_value_ptr=0x7fb62c4108a0, this_ptr=0x7fb62ebbe470, return_value_used=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c:931
#16 0x00007fb62102ab69 in dtrace_execute_internal (execute_data_ptr=<value optimized out>, fci=<value optimized out>, return_value_used=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:97
#17 0x00007fb6210b9b15 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:560
#18 0x00007fb6210a95e8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c410d18) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#19 0x00007fb62102ac9e in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c410d18) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#20 0x00007fb6210ba184 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#21 0x00007fb6210a95e8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c4106d0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#22 0x00007fb62102ac9e in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c4106d0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#23 0x00007fb6210ba184 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#24 0x00007fb6210a95e8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c410218) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#25 0x00007fb62102ac9e in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c410218) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#26 0x00007fb62102d703 in zend_call_function (fci=0x7fffc3a8c070, fci_cache=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:829
#27 0x00007fb620f7db57 in zif_call_user_func_array (ht=<value optimized out>, return_value=0x7fb62fa20608, return_value_ptr=<value optimized out>, this_ptr=<value optimized out>, return_value_used=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/standard/basic_functions.c:4786
#28 0x00007fb62102ab69 in dtrace_execute_internal (execute_data_ptr=<value optimized out>, fci=<value optimized out>, return_value_used=<value optimized out>)
#29 0x00007fb6210b9b15 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:560
#30 0x00007fb6210a95e8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40fb28) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#31 0x00007fb62102ac9e in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40fb28) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#32 0x00007fb6210ba184 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#33 0x00007fb6210a95e8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40f398) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#34 0x00007fb62102ac9e in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40f398) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#35 0x00007fb6210ba184 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#36 0x00007fb6210a95e8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40eff8) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#37 0x00007fb62102ac9e in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40eff8) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#38 0x00007fb6210ba184 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#39 0x00007fb6210a95e8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40e6c8) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#40 0x00007fb62102ac9e in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fb62c40e6c8) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#41 0x00007fb62103a3ec in zend_execute_scripts (type=8, retval=0x0, file_count=3) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/Zend/zend.c:1341
#42 0x00007fb620fd885a in php_execute_script (primary_file=0x7fffc3a8ec80) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/main/main.c:2613
#43 0x00007fb6210e15fd in php_handler (r=0x7fb62d8a9188) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:667
#44 0x00007fb62c504cd0 in ap_run_handler (r=0x7fb62d8a9188) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/config.c:158
#45 0x00007fb62c50858e in ap_invoke_handler (r=0x7fb62d8a9188) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/config.c:376
#46 0x00007fb62c513c50 in ap_process_request (r=0x7fb62d8a9188)
#47 0x00007fb62c510ac8 in ap_process_http_connection (c=0x7fb62d7fc1d8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/modules/http/http_core.c:190
#48 0x00007fb62c50c7d8 in ap_run_process_connection (c=0x7fb62d7fc1d8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/connection.c:43
#49 0x00007fb62c518ad7 in child_main (child_num_arg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:667
#50 0x00007fb62c518dea in make_child (s=0x7fb62d35a880, slot=2) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:763
#51 0x00007fb62c51911b in startup_children (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>, s=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:781
#52 ap_mpm_run (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>, s=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:1002
#53 0x00007fb62c4f09b0 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffc3a8f248) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/main.c:763
```

Can anyone help me in the right direction for finding out what's wrong, or tell me what's wrong if you know? Is there maybe other differences that could create this issue? For example the PHP.ini file? I know there's a difference in the setup of `date.timezone`, for example.

**Update 1:**

I managed to walk around in the trace file and found out that there was a expected response from the server. It's somewhere when it tries to parse the response it fails. For all I know, the document may be wrong. I think it's a higher possibility it's something wrong in the document or that the application code is wrong, than a bug in PHP itself.

**Update 2:**

When accessing the local variables of the different frames, I can see that we're getting a valid SOAP response from the server. At least now we know that the server is responding as it should. The error thus happen after we've received the response and looks like it's when the library is trying to parse the response.

Accessing frame #9 gives us this:

```
#9  0x00007fb6167e32df in parse_packet_soap (this_ptr=<value optimized out>, buffer=<value optimized out>, buffer_size=<value optimized out>, fn=0x7fb62f990b80, fn_name=<value optimized out>, return_value=0x7fb62ebc6428, soap_headers=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/php_packet_soap.c:328
    param = 0x7fb62fba65a0
    val = <value optimized out>
    tmp = <value optimized out>
    h_param = 0x7fb62fba65e8
    name = <value optimized out>
    ns = 0x7fb62fba52d8 "http://www.winorg.no/webservices"
    fnb = 0x7fb62f990678
    res_count = 1
    envelope_ns = 0x7fb600000000 <Address 0x7fb600000000 out of bounds>
    response = 0x7fb62db0aaa0
    trav = <value optimized out>
    env = <value optimized out>
    head = <value optimized out>
    body = <value optimized out>
    resp = 0x7fb62fbdabd0
    cur = <value optimized out>
    fault = <value optimized out>
    attr = <value optimized out>
    param_count = 0
    soap_version = <value optimized out>
    hdrs = 0x0
```

Accessing frame #10 (last application code frame) gives us this:

```
#10 0x00007fb6167c37e8 in do_soap_call (this_ptr=0x7fb62ebbe470, function=<value optimized out>, function_len=<value optimized out>, arg_count=1, real_args=0x7fb62fa1b750, return_value=0x7fb62ebc6428, location=0x7fb62db932b8 "https://winorgws.flt.no/prod/srv/wsWebUser.asmx", soap_action=<value optimized out>, call_uri=<value optimized out>, soap_headers=0x0, output_headers=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/php-5.6.21/ext/soap/soap.c:2780
    uri = 0x7fb6210138d0
    action = <value optimized out>
    __orig_bailout = 0x7fffc3a8b460
    __bailout = {{__jmpbuf = {0, 6085802679289766135, 0, 140420459902800, 140420459902808, 140736476001800,
          -6085882503037591305, -6117803975593172745}, __mask_was_saved = 0, __saved_mask = {__val = {0, 140420218837248,
            1, 140736476001456, 0, 2, 0, 256, 140420214706271, 140736476001852, 1, 140736476001520, 0, 140420218837248, 0,
            140420218837824}}}}
    __orig_bailout = 0x7fffc3a8d980
    __bailout = {{__jmpbuf = {140420444841072, 6085802679289766135, 0, 140420459902800, 140420459902808, 140736476001800,
          -6085882503037591305, -6117803975453187849}, __mask_was_saved = 0, __saved_mask = {__val = {140420214708469,
            206158430248, 140736476001696, 140736476001488, 140420403240512, 140420218837248, 140420427649664,
            140736476001856, 140736476001868, 140736476001824, 140736476001848, 140736476001552, 140420444873432,
            140420444873672, 140736476001760, 140420215755228}}}}
    tmp = 0x7fb62ebc1ad8
    trace = 0x7fb621435900
    sdl = 0x7fb62db91f30
    old_sdl = 0x0
    fn = <value optimized out>
    request = <value optimized out>
    ret = 1
    soap_version = 2
    response = {value = {lval = 140420461530552, dval = 6.9376926015418089e-310, str = {
          val = 0x7fb62fba8db8 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSch"...,
          len = 7635}, ht = 0x7fb62fba8db8, obj = {handle = 800755128, handlers = 0x1dd3}, ast = 0x7fb62fba8db8},
      refcount__gc = 1, type = 6 '\006', is_ref__gc = 0 '\000'}
    old_encoding = 0x0
    old_class_map = 0x0
    old_features = 0
    old_typemap = 0x0
    typemap = <value optimized out>
    _old_handler = 0 '\000'
    _old_error_code = 0x0
    _old_error_object = 0x0
    _old_soap_version = 1
    _old_in_compilation = 0 '\000'
    _old_in_execution = 1 '\001'
    _old_current_execute_data = 0x7fffc3a8b720
    _old_stack_top = 0x7fb62c410e88
    _bailout = 0
```

Here we can see that we indeed have a response. I won't post the full response here as it contains sensitive data.

I also see that the response is somehow escaped with backslashes. I guess this is normal. Is it?

Comment: Does it happen every time? Always for the same method call? Always while talking generally to the same SOAP server? Are data on test and prod env exactly the same? Have you tried to intercept what has been sent and what is coming back and try to use it to do tests on test env.

Comment: The problems is that this doesn't happen on the test environment. Only in the production environment.

As for answering your questions: Yes, it does happen every time. Yes, the same method call. Always the same SOAP server. Same data, except for the database.

I know that on the test server it sends/receives 528 packets in total, and for the production environment, it's only 28 packets. So something is terrible wrong here.

Comment: Tricky case. I would try to intercept communication and see what php is sending and what it is receiving back and compare that with test env. It can be anything. Maybe something went wrong during upgrade, and eg. some package/lib hasn't been upgraded. Maybe some firewall or whatever between you and soap server has shattered messages. If that is possible, ask counterpart if they are receiving connection from you at all during those failing requests. Or maybe that's a bug in PHP (thus intercepting some data would be useful to validate that possibility eventually).

Comment: I think it worth an upstream bug report, il you are able to provide a reproducer.

Comment: If it indeed was a bug, this would happen on all the environment, right? It's only on the production server. Should I check for some other versions of for example the extension for SOAP?

Comment: Invalid answer from SoapServer should not cause a segfault. And there can be some difference in configurations of your environments (different versions of libs used by php), or in configurations of Soap servers, so they may be returning different responses to you, and therefore causing different behaviour. That can be helpful for debugging: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6279/on-the-fly-monitoring-http-requests-on-a-network-interface

Comment: OK. I think the more likely problem is that the configuration on our servers are wrong, as the SOAP server is exactly the same. I'll have a look at the question you linked.

Comment: To add to what @michaJlS said above, specifically compare libxml versions, and if using https, openssl versions (versions can be seen in  phpinfo() output).  You might have to upgrade these libraries as well.

Comment: I've also seen some bugs with the libcurl version as well, when working with SOAP. I'll try to run a phpinfo() on the server.

Comment: When running phpinfo() I don't get any versioning for all the libraries, only some. I can't get the version of the SOAP library for example.

Comment: When accessing frame 9 of the stack trace and printing out local variables with `info locals` it gives me alot of data, but this one doesn't look good: `envelope_ns = 0x7fb600000000 <Address 0x7fb600000000 out of bounds>`. Is this something that tries to access memory it doesn't have access to, and causes a segmentation fault? It looks like the envelope namespace in SOAP.